# Print multiple search pattern in one line + text manipulation

Tags: text-processing

My output looks like this:

```
 /map1/firmware1   Targets   Properties
     version=2.44
     date=Jul 19 2016
     name=iLO 4
```

My desired output is:

```
version=2.44 date=Jul_19_2016
```

To merge the output into one line I tried to use `xargs`. But then he only prints date.

```
cat test | egrep '(version=|date=)' |xargs
 date=Jul 19 2016
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OP's issue seems to be due to `dos` style line endings...

Example:

```
$ cat -e chk 
 /map1/firmware1   Targets   Properties^M$
     version=2.44^M$
     date=Jul 19 2016^M$
     name=iLO 4^M$

$ egrep '(version=|date=)' chk | xargs
 date=Jul 19 2016
```

After converting to `unix` style line ending:

```
$ perl -i -pe 's|\r\n|\n|' chk 

$ cat -e chk 
 /map1/firmware1   Targets   Properties$
     version=2.44$
     date=Jul 19 2016$
     name=iLO 4$

$ egrep '(version=|date=)' chk | xargs
version=2.44 date=Jul 19 2016
```

Comment: paste leads also to the missing version
`egrep '(version=|date=)' test |paste - -`
            `date=Jul 19 2016`

Comment: what is the output of `file test` ? does it have `CRLF line terminators`?

Comment: `file test`
`test: ascii text`
But I think you are right and there are diffrent line terminators. The output comes directly from an HP ILO

Answer (score 1):

using `sed` one-liner

```
$ sed -n '/version/ {N; s/[\r\n]//g; p}' filename
     version=2.44     date=Jul 19 2016
```

#### Explanation

- `/version/` matches pattern and executes the brace block `{ }`.
- `N` takes next line from input file and appends it to pattern space.
- `s/[\r\n]//g` removes all newlines and carriage returns from pattern space.
- `p` prints pattern space.

Comment: This works "half" :) I think that the output format will be the same over multiple servers, so I guess its okay to use "print next line after match". But I still want to swap the spaces in "date=Jul 19 2016" with _